# Net Core WebApi 2.1 and Angular 2 app - IIS Deployment

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.1

WebApi (outofprocess) [VS2017: Publish] and Angular [build --prod] hosted in IIS on same port:80 on IIS 10. Angular build in wwwroot and webapi in api folders with ApplicationPool with IUSR access to hosting file folder. The index.html loads correctly.

But the following uri: http://website.com/applicationusers/authenticate [two parameters: username and password] returns the following error: "ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

I noticed that IIS is not starting/loading dotnet.exe as I do not see it in the task manager.

But when I run dotnet.exe website.dll in command prompt, the api loads up at localhost:5000 and when I test it in postman using the following: http://localhost:5000/api/applicationusers/authenticate I get a response.

Is there something I am missing that's causing the issue IIS... appreciate any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

It seems this error is generating when you are trying to calling your REST end points from the angular application for authentication.Try to add promise or observable while calling the rest end point from angular application.

Comment: I tried but I am not getting it right. Following is my method: 
login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/applicationusers/authenticate`, { username: username, password: password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                if (user && user.token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    return user;
                }
 }